# jQuery custom validation: custom phone number format

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, phone-number

I have a form in which you have to input your phone number and other fields.

I'm validating the form with jQuery Validate.

To validate the phone number field I do:

```
rules: {
    phone: {
    required: true,
        minlength: 9,
        number:true
    },..
```

But I need to check also that phone starts with 6.

How can I do that?

Comment: "by" => "with", just FYI: "phone number starting **with** 6"

Comment: ooops, thanks, to much in a rush for spelling :)

Comment: @user: It's not just you, I see that a *lot*. :-) The number of times I've seen "how do I replace X by Y?"... I figure there's a widely-spoken language out there where the analog of "by" is used in that situation, and people translating are translating too literally. It's **very** forgiveable. :-)

Answer (score 7):

You can add a custom validator

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneStartingWith6", function(phone_number, element) {
    phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, ""); 
    return this.optional(element) || phone_number.match(/^6\d{8,}$/);
}, "Phone number should start with 6");
```

and use it like this:

```
rules: {
    phone: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 9,
        phoneEnding6: true
    },..
```

You need to edit the regex inside `phone_number.match` to suit your requirements.

Comment: If it solves your problem, you can accept it as an answer by clicking the big checkbox on the left to accept it (unless you are expecting a better answer). :)

Comment: this works great, except the method name is misleading. Should it be `phoneStarting6` ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need to add a custom validator.

```
$.validator.addMethod("phoneNumber", function(uid, element) {
    return (this.optional(element) || uid.match(phone number regex));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try simple Javascript function

```
"Hello World!".startsWith("He"); //true
```

Note: This comment/code is for those who are not using jquery validate.