# jQuery validate number that does NOT begins with 0 or 1

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

A quick one.

I use jQuery validate, and need to validate a phonenumber that can't begin with 0 or 1.

A similar question has been posted in [jQuery custom validation: phone number starting with 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4490622/569659), but where it SHOULD start with 6. I've tried to modify it to fit my needs - but without any luck.

```
            phone_nr: {      
              maxlength: 8,
              minlength: 8,
              number: true
            }
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a custom function like the answers to the other question, but with a regular expression matching every digit apart from 0 or 1, e.g.:

```
phone_number.match(/^[2-9]\d+$/
```